# Why is PrivateWorkForce on AWS failing to delete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to create an AWS Custom Labels Cloudstack via the template provided by AWS:

https://ml-specialist-sa-demo-us-east-2.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/custom-brand-detection/1.0.0/amazon-rekognition-custom-brand-detection.template

At first, I ran into the following issue which was displayed in the console:

Resource handler returned message: "The runtime parameter of nodejs10.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs18.x) while creating or updating functions.

I updated the Node version to ^20 as well as the aws-sdk's. I rebuilt, deployed and attempted to create the stack but it failed because a previous resource wouldn't delete and the console stated the following reason:

Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk' Require stack: - /var/task/lib/sagemaker/privateWorkforce.js - /var/task/lib/sagemaker/index.js - /var/task/index.js - /var/runtime/index.mjs.

I've also tried deleting the previous stacks but I'm still getting this error.

I've been looking around but can't seems to find an answer for this and attempted to reach out to AWS for an updated template but they provided a template that was also out of date so I'm not sure what to do at this point. If anyone has suggestions or can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,

Nick

Index.js

```
    const PrivateWorkforce = require('./privateWorkforce');

exports.PrivateWorkforceConfiguration = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const workteam = new PrivateWorkforce(event, context);
    return workteam.isRequestType('Delete')
      ? workteam.deleteResource()
      : workteam.isRequestType('Update')
        ? workteam.updateResource()
        : workteam.createResource();
  } catch (e) {
    e.message = `PrivateWorkforceConfiguration: ${e.message}`;
    throw e;
  }
};
```

privateWorkforce.js

```
const FS = require('fs');
const PATH = require('path');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const mxBaseResponse = require('../shared/mxBaseResponse');

class PrivateWorkforce extends mxBaseResponse(class {}) {
  constructor(event, context) {
    super(event, context);
    /* sanity check */
    const data = event.ResourceProperties.Data;
    this.sanityCheck(data);
    this.$data = data;

    this.$cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
      apiVersion: '2016-04-18',
    });

    this.$sagemaker = new AWS.SageMaker({
      apiVersion: '2017-07-24',
    });
  }

  sanityCheck(data) {
    const missing = [
      'SolutionId',
      'UserPool',
      'UserGroup',
      'AppClientId',
      'TopicArn',
      'UserPoolDomain',
    ].filter(x => data[x] === undefined);
    if (missing.length) {
      throw new Error(`missing ${missing.join(', ')}`);
    }
  }

  get data() {
    return this.$data;
  }

  get solutionId() {
    return this.data.SolutionId;
  }

  get userPool() {
    return this.data.UserPool;
  }

  get userGroup() {
    return this.data.UserGroup;
  }

  get clientId() {
    return this.data.AppClientId;
  }

  get topicArn() {
    return this.data.TopicArn;
  }

  get userPoolDomain() {
    return this.data.UserPoolDomain;
  }

  get workteamName() {
    return `${this.userPoolDomain}-team`;
  }

  get cognito() {
    return this.$cognito;
  }

  get sagemaker() {
    return this.$sagemaker;
  }

  normalize(name) {
    return name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '-');
  }

  async preconfigure() {
   
    await this.cognito.createUserPoolDomain({
      Domain: this.userPoolDomain,
      UserPoolId: this.userPool,
    }).promise();

    
    await this.cognito.updateUserPoolClient({
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      UserPoolId: this.userPool,
      AllowedOAuthFlows: [
        'code',
        'implicit',
      ],
      AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true,
      AllowedOAuthScopes: [
        'email',
        'openid',
        'profile',
      ],
      ExplicitAuthFlows: [
        'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
      ],
    
      CallbackURLs: [
        'https://127.0.0.1',
      ],
      LogoutURLs: [
        'https://127.0.0.1',
      ],
      SupportedIdentityProviders: [
        'COGNITO',
      ],
    }).promise();
  }

  async queryCurrentTeam() {
    const {
      Workteams,
    } = await this.sagemaker.listWorkteams({
      MaxResults: 100,
    }).promise();

    if (!Workteams.length) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const team = Workteams.shift();
    if (!team.MemberDefinitions || !team.MemberDefinitions.length) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const {
      CognitoMemberDefinition,
    } = team.MemberDefinitions.shift();

    return {
      UserPool: CognitoMemberDefinition.UserPool,
      ClientId: CognitoMemberDefinition.ClientId,
    };
  }

  async cognitoCreateGroup(userPool) {
    if (!userPool) {
      throw new Error('cognitoCreateGroup - userPool is null');
    }

    return this.cognito.createGroup({
      GroupName: this.userGroup,
      Description: `${this.solutionId} labeling workteam user group`,
      UserPoolId: userPool,
    }).promise();
  }

  async createTeam(current = {}) {
 
    if (current.UserPool) {
      await this.cognitoCreateGroup(current.UserPool);
    }

    const params = {
      Description: `(${this.solutionId}) labeling workteam`,
      MemberDefinitions: [{
        CognitoMemberDefinition: {
          UserPool: current.UserPool || this.userPool,
          ClientId: current.ClientId || this.clientId,
          UserGroup: this.userGroup,
        },
      }],
      WorkteamName: this.workteamName,
      NotificationConfiguration: {
        NotificationTopicArn: this.topicArn,
      },
      Tags: [
        {
          Key: 'SolutionId',
          Value: this.solutionId,
        },
      ],
    };

    await this.sagemaker.createWorkteam(params).promise();

    const {
      Workteam,
    } = await this.sagemaker.describeWorkteam({
      WorkteamName: this.workteamName,
    }).promise();

    return Workteam;
  }

  async postconfigure(team = {}) {
    if (!team.SubDomain) {
      throw new Error('postconfigure - SubDomain is null');
    }

    let template = PATH.join(PATH.dirname(__filename), 'fixtures/email.template');
    template = FS.readFileSync(template);
    template = template.toString().replace(/%URI%/g, `https://${team.SubDomain}`);

    await this.cognito.updateUserPool({
      UserPoolId: this.userPool,
      AdminCreateUserConfig: {
        AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true,
        InviteMessageTemplate: {
          EmailMessage: template,
          EmailSubject: `You are invited by ${this.workteamName} to work on a labeling project.`,
        },
      },
    }).promise();
  }

  async createResource() {
    await this.preconfigure();
    const current = await this.queryCurrentTeam();
    const team = await this.createTeam(current);
    await this.postconfigure(team);

    this.storeResponseData('UserPool', (current && current.UserPool) || this.userPool);
    this.storeResponseData('ClientId', (current && current.ClientId) || this.clientId);
    this.storeResponseData('UserGroup', this.userGroup);
    this.storeResponseData('TeamName', this.workteamName);
    this.storeResponseData('TeamArn', team.WorkteamArn);
    this.storeResponseData('Status', 'SUCCESS');

    return this.responseData;
  }

  async deleteResource() {
    try {
      const {
        Workteam,
      } = await this.sagemaker.describeWorkteam({
        WorkteamName: this.workteamName,
      }).promise();

      /* delete workteam only if it exists */
      if ((Workteam || {}).WorkteamArn) {
        const {
          Success,
        } = await this.sagemaker.deleteWorkteam({
          WorkteamName: this.workteamName,
        }).promise();

        if (!Success) {
          throw new Error(`failed to delete Workteam, ${this.workteamName}`);
        }
      }

      /* delete user group */
      if ((Workteam || {}).MemberDefinitions) {
        const {
          UserGroup,
          UserPool,
        } = (Workteam.MemberDefinitions.shift() || {}).CognitoMemberDefinition || {};

       
        if (UserGroup && UserPool && this.userPool !== UserPool) {
          await this.cognito.deleteGroup({
            GroupName: UserGroup,
            UserPoolId: UserPool,
          }).promise();
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    try {
      const response = await this.cognito.describeUserPoolDomain({
        Domain: this.userPoolDomain,
      }).promise();

      /* delete domain only if it exists */
      if (((response || {}).DomainDescription || {}).Domain) {
        await this.cognito.deleteUserPoolDomain({
          Domain: this.userPoolDomain,
          UserPoolId: this.userPool,
        }).promise();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    this.storeResponseData('Status', 'DELETED');

    return this.responseData;
  }

  async updateResource() {
    await this.deleteResource();
    return this.createResource();
  }

  async configure() {
    if (this.isRequestType('Delete')) {
      return this.deleteResource();
    }

    if (this.isRequestType('Update')) {
      return this.updateResource();
    }

    return this.createResource();
  }
}

module.exports = PrivateWorkforce;
```

package.json

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/package",
  "name": "custom-resources",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "(Custom Brand Detection) AWS CloudFormation Custom Resource Lambda function",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "mocha *.spec.js",
    "build:clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir -p dist",
    "build:copy": "cp -rv index.js package.json lib dist/",
    "build:install": "cd dist && npm install --production",
    "build": "npm-run-all -s build:clean build:copy build:install",
    "zip": "cd dist && zip -rq"
  },
  "author": "aws-specialist-sa-emea",
  "license": "MIT-0",
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.14",
    "mime": "^2.4.5",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sagemaker": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "core-lib": "file:../layers/core-lib"
  }
}
```

Comment: The lambda code will likely need to be updated for the latest version. I'm reaching out to the blog post authors.

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks, I'd really appreciate that. Yeah, the blog post is dated Jan 2021 so the template urls referenced in that are probably as old as the post itself. I'm trying to use this in the Media2Cloud context which references a GitHub repo to use for this but I've been told by AWS support that that repo isn't managed by AWS anymore. I've been trying to debug myself but I keep running into errors though so any help would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @EricZBeard , just wanted to see if you had any luck with the blog authors. AWS support escalated my ticket regarding this but I haven't had a positive response yet. Thanks- Nick

Comment: Not yet, sorry, looks like one or both authors may have left the company.

Comment: Thanks @EricZBeard , I got something from AWS support the other day informing me that they were working on the github issue but they didn't provide a solution ETA. Any pointers, advice, resources, etc. regarding how to approach this would be helpful. Thanks again for the help. - Nick